# Garbage collection of referenced objects

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

Let's say I have a class referencing another class like this:

```
class1
{

}

class2
{
    int A;
    class1 B;

    public class2(int a, class1 b){
        A =a;
        B = b;
    }
```

Now in another method I create a new instance:

```
class3
{
    class2 myobject;

    mymethod()
    {
        class2 myobject = new class2(45, new class1( some parameters));
    }
}
```

When the new `class1`(some parameters) memory will be free?

Comment: I note that you have a local and an instance variable of the same name; is this intentional?

Comment: Since it makes a big difference whether the variable is local or instance to the garbage collection semantics, that's a bit unfortunate.

Answer (score 5):

> When will the newly create instance of class1 be freed?

It is impossible to say for certain. The garbage collector can free it at a time of its choosing, or choose to never free it.

> What is the latest that the memory could be freed?

There is no requirement that the memory ever be freed. The program could run forever and never do a collection.

> What is the earliest that the memory could be freed?

It could be freed *immediately after the instance of `class2` was allocated*. Given that the local variable is never read, there is no requirement for the local variable to actually exist. The jitter can optimize it away, which means that there is no gc root for `class2`, so it can be freed immediately, and therefore so can the instance of `class1` which it is holding.

More generally: though it is good that you're wanting to learn how the runtime works, don't stress about it. 99.99% of the time the garbage collector does exactly what you want it to without you thinking about it.

Answer (score 2):

An object is released by garbage collector when there are no references to it and that object cant be accessed any more.

Edit :
As mentioned *Theodoros Chatzigiannakis*, after the garbage collector calls the object’s finalizer, the object becomes eligible for garbage
collection. The memory for such an object can be reclaimed by the garbage collector. But we don't know when it will be collected.

A problem with the garbage collector is that it doesn’t guarantee that it will perform
its tasks at a specified time. Therefore, the garbage collector may call the finalizer any
time after the object becomes unreachable, and may reclaim the memory any
time after the finalizer executes. In fact, it’s possible that neither will happen before the app terminates. Thus, it’s unclear whether, or when, the finalizer will be called. For this reason, finalizers are rarely used.

For example :

```
classObj obj = new classObj(); 
//we create an new object in memory (by invoking new classObj()) 
//and obj refers to it.

obj = null; 
//now we change obj's reference to null but object 
//that we created in memory still exists
```

Comment: Eligible, not necessarily released.

Comment: so both setting myobject to null or setting Bfielnd in my object to null would work for example?

Comment: Don't use strings as example. They are interned, so `"abc"` will never be collected.

Comment: `obj = null;` is good for explaining this but it is a bad practice in general code.

Comment: None of the objects in the example have destructors.